# Extracting url from style: background-url: with beautifulsoup and without regex?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg');"
```

I want to get the url, however I don't know how to do that without the use of regex. Is it even possible?

so far my solution with regex is:

```
url = re.findall('\('(.*?)'\)', soup['style'])[0]
```

Comment: why do you want to make it without regex?

Comment: @WKPlus I'm just curious more than anything else. I read bs4 docs and couldn't find anything so I thought maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try using the [cssutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssutils/1.0) package. Something like this should work:

```
import cssutils
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="image" style="background-image: url('/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg');" />"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div_style = soup.find('div')['style']
style = cssutils.parseStyle(div_style)
url = style['background-image']

>>> url
u'url(/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg)'
>>> url = url.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '')    # or regex/split/find/slice etc.
>>> url
u'/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg'
```

Although you are ultimately going to need to parse out the actual url this method should be more resilient to changes in the HTML. If you really dislike string manipulation and regex, you can pull the url out in this roundabout way:

```
sheet = cssutils.css.CSSStyleSheet()
sheet.add("dummy_selector { %s }" % div_style)
url = list(cssutils.getUrls(sheet))[0]
>>> url
u'/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg'
```

Comment: for some reason the style is coming empty at my end. It might be searching in the webpage's stylesheet instead of the inline style attribute?

Comment: @nikhilvj: I have no idea what web page or code you are using. If you are having a problem then you could post a question that better details your problem

Comment: In case you want to disable unwanted warning message in you output use `import logging;cssutils.log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> style
'<div ... url(\'/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg\');"'
>>> style.split("('", 1)[1].split("')")[0]
'/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """<div class="image" style="background-image: url('/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg');"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
image_div = soup.find('div')['style']

ptr = re.search("http.*[)]",image_div) # regex to search url till ')'
print(image_div[ptr.start():ptr.end()-1]) # end() -1 to remove ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you can just use `str.find` and str slice:

```
>>> s
"background-image: url('/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg');"
>>> s.find("('")
21
>>> s.find("')")
68
>>> s[21+len("('"):68]
'/uploads/images/players/16113-1399107741.jpeg'
```

But however, I think it's better to use regex in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex option, to make sure the "background-image: url" is also matched:

```
re.findall(".*background-image *: *url\((.*)\)", soup["style"])[0]
```

If you also want to remove quotes, this should do it:

```
re.findall(".*background-image *: *url\((.*)\)", soup["style"])[0].strip(" \'\"")
```