# Scrapy - need help extracting string out of style attribute

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the image src from the style attribute using python and scrapy.

This is the tag:

```
<div class="media-img"><div class=" searched-img" style="background-image: url(https://media.ziparound.com.au/EEE/2/83B5-5588AF298562/1450507652885_dww-eegee.jpg);"></div>
```

I can extract the whole style using this:

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'media-img')]//@style").extract_first()
```

I get

```
'background-image: url(https://media.ziparound.com.au/EEE/2/83B5-5588AF298562/1450507652885_dww-eegee.jpg);
```

but I can't figure out how to just extract the image src

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting url from style: background-url: with beautifulsoup and without regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981963/extracting-url-from-style-background-url-with-beautifulsoup-and-without-regex)

Comment: I want to use regex, the other question is without regex plus I'm using Scrapy, the other solution isn't

Comment: You need to use `response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'media-img')]//@style").re_first(r'url\(([^\)]+)')`

Comment: @gangabass solution will work but you should use something  like `url\((.*)\);` because `()` is allow withouth encoding in urls.